# I'm getting an error "Spread types may only be created from object types.ts(2698)"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirestoreDbService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  getBuildList() {
    // return this.db.collection('Builds').valueChanges();
    return this.db.collection('Builds').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          console.log('==', doc.payload.doc.id);
          console.log('$==$', doc.payload.doc.data());
          return{
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            ... doc.payload.doc.data()
          }
        })
      })
    )
  }
}
```

On the last line I am getting the error. I think this is something to do with typescript. Any help appreciated

Comment: Check the return type of `doc.payload.doc.data()`. It is not or not always an object, so typescript is sure that you can't safely spread.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the `as` keyword:

```
... doc.payload.doc.data() as {}
```

This will tell the compiler to treat `doc.payload.doc.data()` as an object.

Comment: is this due to strictness? why does typescript make us cheat on it?

Comment: i was able to get rid of the same error via this answer. in my case, i am converting a functional component into a class based one. thanks!

Comment: @kvicera no problem!

Comment: If you have typescript-eslint installed, seems like this could throw a linting error according to the eslint rule, `eslint@typescript-eslint/ban-types`. See [the docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/).